# How to PERMANENTLY disable mouse accelleration in 17.04?

Tags: mouse, xinput

I've managed to disable mouse acceleration in 17.04 with the following command:

```
xinput --set-prop 8 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
```

However! As soon as I restart the computer, the setting is no longer in effect. How do I make it permanent?

Comment: I would answer this but really, this is just asking for "how to run a command at startup".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the line at the end of ~/.profile

Open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)

Use your text editor of choice to edit '~/.profile'

```
$ nano ~/.profile
```

Add the following line at the bottom of the text file.

```
xinput --set-prop 8 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
```

8 is the id of the mouse I want the settings applied to. In your case, this number can be something else. You can list your devices with `xinput -list` to figure out what yours is.

Save the changes, and the command should be executed every time you log on to your desktop.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? the answer must be understandable for other people as well

Comment: You can use `gedit ~/.profile` instead of `gedit /home/user/.profile` so we won't have to replace the `user` string.